# How to find all subarrays with sum k in O(n) time complexity?

Tags: java, arrays

I can search for a subarrays with a sum k with the below code :

```
public static void subarraySum(int[] arr, int sum) {

    int start=0;
    int currSum=arr[0];

    for(int i = 1;i<=arr.length;i++) {
        while(currSum>sum ) {
            currSum-=arr[start];
            start++;
        }
        if(currSum==sum) {
            System.out.println(start + " " + (i-1) + " index");
            start=i;
            currSum=0;
        }
        if(i<arr.length) {
            currSum +=arr[i];
        }

    }
```

This will work for array like {15,2,4,8,9,5,10,23}. Output for this will be 2 subarrays {2,4,9,8} and {23}.

However, for arrays like {1,5,2,5,1,3}, this will only give me output as 1 subarray however there are 2 subarrays with sum 7 which are {5,2} and {2,5}. 
Any suggestions on how to tweek the above code to give the correct answer in the 2nd array ?

Answer (score 4):

The algorithm is not complicated, I will explain the idea and leave the implementation to you to try it.

You need to have two indexes `i`, `j`. Make them both start with the first element. Now take the sub array between them (initially since they are both in the same place no sub array) and do the following test:

- if the sum of it equals to your goal then add the current sub array
- if the sum is less than your goal move `j` to the right to include one 
  more element and do the test again
- if the sum is greater than your goal move `i` to the right to remove
  the first element from the subarray and do the test again.

Finally, you will be having all the subarrays with sum equalling your goal.

> please note that this solution only works for positive numbers

Comment: Are you referring to running 2 loops ?

Comment: @brij not really , it should be done in one loop, the only loop you need is to iterate and do the test i mentioned

Comment: in the first point when sum is equal to my goal, what value should I reassign to i and j ?

Comment: @brij since the numbers are positive you will need to remove the first element (increment i) , if we know there are no zeros we could in the same move,  move both i and j

Comment: but then if I move both i and j to the current position, an array like {1,5,2,5,1,3} will again give me a single subarray {5,2} and not 2 subarrays, isn't it ?

Comment: no , if i on the first 5, j on 2 , then this is goal so this is the first subarray, so we move both to the right, now i is on 2 and j is on second 5 then this is another goal so we store the second subarray

Comment: In the above code as well, I have maintained 2 index, start and i. And then I have moved start to i if curr_sum is equal to my goal. Isn't this exactly the same way that you are referring or am I missing something ?

Comment: your code has some problem , see if your first element is less than the sum then your loop will never stop since currentSum will never be greater than the sum, try to translate the algorithm i provided and you will get your result

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am too slow. While I was solving this problem to give a code, we have a corrent algorytm answer. +1 for it from me and optionally my solution with code *(I had this question in interview many ears ago)*:

```
public static List<int[]> subarraySum(int[] arr, int sum) {
    List<int[]> res = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] tmp;
    int start = 0;  // inclusive
    int end = 0;    // exclusive
    int currSum = 0;

    do {
        if (end == arr.length && currSum < sum)
            break;
        if (currSum > sum)
            currSum -= arr[start++];
        else if (currSum < sum)
            currSum += arr[end++];
        else if (currSum == sum) {
            res.add(tmp = new int[end - start]);
            System.arraycopy(arr, start, tmp, 0, tmp.length);
            currSum -= arr[start];
            start++;
        }
    } while (start <= arr.length && end <= arr.length);

    return res;
}
```

It looks correct, but I have tested this solution only in a couple of cases.